# Oracle 11g increasing shared pool size and java pool size

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, memory

i need to install/configure oracle jvm on 11g. to be able to install same i need to increase the size of shared_pool_size and java_pool_size. i have automatic memory management enabled. my sga_max_size = 512M. 
Can any one advise how to change the shared/java pool.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You're have AMM enabled, so Oracle will manage it for you automatically. `SGA_TARGET` will be set to a non-zero value, which means:

> Specifies the total size of all SGA components. If SGA_TARGET is 
>   specified, then the buffer cache (DB_CACHE_SIZE), Java pool 
>   (JAVA_POOL_SIZE), large pool (LARGE_POOL_SIZE), and shared pool 
>   (SHARED_POOL_SIZE) memory pools are automatically sized.

You can set it to a non-zero value that is equal to or less than `SGA_MAX_SIZE`, so if you need to allocate more memory, just up `SGA_MAX_SIZE` and `SGA_TARGET`.

eg:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET SGA_MAX_SIZE = 2048M;
ALTER SYSTEM SET SGA_TARGET = 2048M;
```

See [this documentation section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/memory004.htm) (search for "Enabling Automatic Shared Memory Management") - Read that whole documentation section to gain a better understanding.

As an aside, your `SGA_MAX_SIZE` does seem very small.

Comment: thnxs phill.
so in my case where amm is enable, i dont need to increase shared memory and java memory?

as for the sga_max_size, it should be less than the ram right?

Comment: Hi. Would be grateful to get your opinion on my issue here https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/265187/180495