# Tuning Java Pool after getting ORA-04031

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, database-tuning

I'm running Oracle 12.2.0.1 Standard edition on Windows 2012 RC2. 
I'm NOT running Oracle's Automatic Memory Management.

We are seeing these in the alert log:

```
ORA-04031: unable to allocate 4096 bytes of shared memory ("java pool","prv//////LBKLAGIMAAAAAAAA","JOXLE^aff7380e",":SGAClass")
```

First thing I thought to try was flushing the shared pool to resolve the immediate problem, while the dev team is fixing the SQL code, so I ran:

```
ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL;
```

Only then did I realise that the Java Pool isn't actually part of the shared pool. So I tried to take a look at the Java pool.

I think this tells me that my Java pool is roughly 32MB:

```
SQL> select * from v$javapool;
```

> ```
> CATEGORY                                            MEMUSED     CON_ID
> ------------------------------------------------ ---------- ----------
> :Intern                                              973440          0
> :SGAClass                                          32103240          0
> :SROState                                             81120          0
> ```

I ran this tuning tool, which if I can interpret correctly, says that there's not much benefit from increasing the Java pool size:

```
    select
       estd_lc_size,
       java_pool_size_for_estimate,
       java_pool_size_factor
    from
       v$java_pool_advice;
```

> ```
> ESTD_LC_SIZE JAVA_POOL_SIZE_FOR_ESTIMATE JAVA_POOL_SIZE_FACTOR
> ------------ --------------------------- ---------------------
>            8                          16                    .5
>           24                          32                     1
>           25                          48                   1.5
>           25                          64                     2
>           25                          80                   2.5
>           25                          96                     3
>           25                         112                   3.5
>           25                         128                     4
>           25                         144                   4.5
>           25                         160                     5
>           25                         176                   5.5
> ```

I ran the following query [taken from the Oracle docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/managing-memory.html#GUID-0E0EBCD5-6134-492B-9232-3F76D92B1900) and it seems to suggest that the SGA_TARGET value is fine!

```
SELECT (
   (SELECT SUM(value) FROM V$SGA) -
   (SELECT CURRENT_SIZE FROM V$SGA_DYNAMIC_FREE_MEMORY)
   ) "SGA_TARGET"
FROM DUAL;
```

> ```
> SGA_TARGET
> ----------
> 5167382528 = 4928 MB i.e. same as what it currently is!
> ```

I can see that:

```
    MEMORY_TARGET = 0
    SGA_MAX_SIZE = 4928M
    SGA_TARGET = 4928M
    JAVA_POOL_SIZE = 0
    SHARED_POOL_SIZE = 0
    DB_CACHE_SIZE = 0 
    DB_KEEP_CACHE_SIZE = 0
    MEMORY_MAX_TARGET = 0
```

...so I'm bit confused how to tune this when we're not using AMM.

So how to resolve this issue?

1. is my best option to increase the Java pool size?
2. if so, how to do this when not using AMM?

Comment: What values do you have for the other memory relevant settings? `SHARED_POOL`, `DB_CACHE_SIZE`, `DB_KEEP_CACHE_SIZE` and other memory parameters? Is anything set for `MEMORY_MAX_TARGET`? Add the information to your question by hitting the [edit] button.

Comment: Nearly forgot: How much memory (RAM) does your system (laptop, desktop, server) have?

Comment: Hi John, I've added those values. Let me know if there are other ones you would like to know. In general I can say that this system has never been tuned, and is using the Oracle defaults. Thanks!

Comment: RAM on this server = 16GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AMM or ASMM?

There are two forms of Memory Management in an Oracle Database instance:

1. Automatic Memory Management (AMM)
2. Automatic Shared Memory Managemnt (ASMM)

If you were to have set values for the `MEMORY_MAX_TARGET` and `MEMORY_TARGET` then you would be in AMM mode. Your Oracle instances will assign memory up until the `MEMORY_TARGET` setting. If you were to notice a performance impact then you could increase the `MEMORY_TARGET` value up until the `MEMORY_MAX_TARGET` size without having to restart the instance.

If you haven't set the `MEMORY_MAX_TARGET`and the `MEMORY_TARGET` values for your instance, then we can assume that you are in ASMM mode, because you have set a value for the `SGA_TARGET` parameter.

When in ASMM mode the following parameters are automatically configured:

> **Table 6-2 Automatically Sized SGA Components and Corresponding Parameters**
>   SHARE_POOL_SIZE
>   LARGE_POOL_SIZE
>   JAVA_POOL_SIZE
>   DB_CACHE_SIZE
>   STREAMS_POOL_SIZE

<sup>***Reference:*** [Table 6-2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/managing-memory.html#GUID-1B568DEC-AAC0-4626-B44C-A6D446077032__BABDCHDE)  (Oracle Docs)</sup>

There is also the following small note which indicates:

> In addition to setting `SGA_TARGET` to a nonzero value, you must set to zero all initialization parameters listed in Table 6-2 to enable full automatic tuning of the automatically sized SGA components.

So there is no need to set the `JAVA_POOL_SIZE` to a non-zero value, unless you want to manually assign a minimum value for the parameter. Otherwise, Oracle will assign memory inside the boundaries of your `SGA_TARGET` size, which is currently slightly over 4 GB (`4928M`).

### What is using SGA_TARGET?

Then there is the hint that:

<sub>(**emphasis** mine)</sub>

> The manually sized parameters listed in **Table 6-3**, if they are set, take their memory from `SGA_TARGET`, **leaving what is available for the components listed in Table 6-2.**

The parameters in **Table 6-3** are:

> LOG_BUFFER
>   DB_KEEP_CACHE_SIZE
>   DB_RECYCLE_CACHE_SIZE
>   DB_nK_CACHE_SIZE

<sup>***Reference:*** [Table 6-3](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/managing-memory.html#GUID-1B568DEC-AAC0-4626-B44C-A6D446077032__BABBDEFJ) (Oracle Docs)</sup>

### Solution

If the components in **table 6-3** are using too much memory, then there isn't enough memory left in the `SGA_TARGET` pool to automatically assign enough memory for the components in **table 6-2** or in your case for the `JAVA_POOL_SIZE` parameter. You can the observe the error:

> ORA-04031: unable to allocate 4096 bytes of shared memory ("java pool","prv//////LBKLAGIMAAAAAAAA","JOXLE^aff7380e",":SGAClass")

You might have to increase the `SGA_TARGET` parameter to a value higher than what you currently have, in order for the SGA Pool to have sufficient memory to automatically be able to tune the dynamic parameters.

Try `8192M` and observe how your Oracle instance responds to these changes.

#### Reference Reading

- [6.4.2.4.1 The SGA Target and Automatically Sized SGA Components](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/managing-memory.html#GUID-1B568DEC-AAC0-4626-B44C-A6D446077032)  (Oracle Docs | 12.2 | Admin Guide)
- [6.4.2 Using Automatic Shared Memory Management](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/managing-memory.html#GUID-3CEA1AB5-4850-4064-9823-F62C500A579F)  (Oracle Docs | 12.2 | Admin Guide)
- [6.3 Using Automatic Memory Management](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/managing-memory.html#GUID-8F54391B-D42A-4FDA-9D12-E1F81FD113EA) (Oracle Docs | 12.2 | Admin Guide)

Comment: Thanks John. That makes more sense that it shouldn't be necessary to manually change the JAVA_POOL_SIZE. I'll increase both SGA_TARGET and SGA_MAX_SIZE to 8192M and see how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks again. I just implemented that and it resolved the ORA-04031 issues with the java pool.

Comment: Nice to hear. Glad I could provide you with an informative answer.

Answer (score 1):

With SGA_TARGET set and JAVA_POOL_SIZE=0 it you are at least using Automatic Shared Memory Management, so the Java Pool is already self-tuning. You can specify a JAVA_POOL_SIZE value that will become the minimum pool size and Oracle may choose to tune it higher if necessary. Changing the JAVA_POOL_SIZE will require a restart of the database. You may need to increase the SGA_TARGET value as well, as increasing the default JAVA_POOL_SIZE will take memory away from other SGA pools.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/JAVA_POOL_SIZE.html#GUID-F24C4770-0B7C-42BD-9AAD-0EC1E92A90F6

Comment: What is the value of MEMORY_TARGET?

Comment: Thanks for responding! MEMORY_TARGET is 0. I have to admit I'm pretty confused. If the Java pool is self tuning, why am I getting the ORA-04031, and why do I need to change JAVA_POOL_SIZE?

Comment: I forgot to ask, what is SGA_MAX_SIZE? Is it also 4920M? Oracle can only tune SGA components within the overall limit the SGA, so it most likely reached a point where it couldn't steal memory from another pool to grow the Java pool. You'll have to decide if you want to set a minimum size for the Java pool, or let Oracle continue to manage everything, but either way you'll need to grow the SGA max and target to make room for the new Java requirements.

Comment: According to this, Oracle recommends a minimum Java pool size of 50M. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDEV/chnine.htm#JJDEV13316

Comment: yes, SGA_MAX_SIZE = 4928M too. I'm happy to let Oracle handle everything. So what's the recommendation here exactly? Increase both SGA_TARGET and SGA_MAX_SIZE and Oracle should handle the rest? Anything else needed?

Comment: Do that, and I would also set the JAVA_POOL_SIZE to 50M, to ensure that it always has at least that much available.